# Is possible add minHeight or make column fit with text inside columnrange on Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, range, axis-labels

I have 3 values on each column (min, medium, max), I need position each box on correct position by value, and if 2 box or 3 box have same value or values very close, I need group (like last box of image), and the boxes need to have minHeight or something like this to fit the text inside:

[image]

I have some code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/to2z4dyv/

New fiddle update:
http://jsfiddle.net/vdgphk3L/

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        grouping: false,
        pointPadding: -0.20
      }
    },


    legend: {
      enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Minimo',
      color: 'green',
      data: [
        [10, 2000, 2999],
        [20, 5000, 6000],
        [30, 3000, 4000],
        [40, 8000, 9000],
        [50, 3500, 4000]
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        borderRadius: 2,
        inside: true,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
        format: '{point.y}',
        //color: 'rgba(0,0,0)'
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Medio',
      color: 'yellow',
      data: [
        [10, 3000, 3999],
        [20, 6001, 7000],
        [30, 4001, 5000],
        [40, 9001, 9500],
        [50, 4001, 4500]
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        borderRadius: 2,
        inside: true,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
        format: '{point.y}',
        //color: 'rgba(0,0,0)'
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Maximo',
      color: 'blue',
      data: [
        [10, 4000, 5000],
        [20, 7001, 8000],
        [30, 5001, 6000],
        [40, 9501, 10000],
        [50, 4501, 5000]
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        borderRadius: 2,
        inside: true,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
        format: '{point.y}',
        //color: 'rgba(0,0,0)'
      }
    }]

  });

});
```

On this example, the [data] have 3 properties, I believe that I need to have only 2, one for the value and the other for the X axis...

Comment: Using something something like `minPointLength` in stacked column / columnrange series looks like complicated concept to me. **Example:** Let's say that all columnranges that have a span less than 100 should look like if they're exactly 100 span - that's our `minHeight` parameter.  There's a point with range from 100 to 180. Do you want it to look like 100-200?

Comment: @KamilKulig Thanks, the minPointLength help me a lot... I'm almost able to do what I need http://jsfiddle.net/vdgphk3L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I archieve this result http://jsfiddle.net/mv9vsmnn/, it was not exactly what I needed, but it solved my problem.

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: false,
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5'],
      alternateGridColor: '#F6F9FC',
    },

    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      width: 20,
      formatter: function() {
        var retorno = '<strong>Prices</strong>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
          if (point.series.name == 'Min' || point.series.name == 'Med' || point.series.name == 'Max') {
            retorno += '<br /><span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + numberToReal(point.y);
          }
        });

        return retorno;
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        grouping: false,
        pointWidth: 70,
        minPointLength: 25,
        dataLabels: {
          inside: true,
          enabled: true,
          allowOverlap: true,
          formatter: function() {
            if (this.y == this.point.low) {
                return this.point.low;
              }
          }
        }
      },
      series: {
        lineWidth: 0.5
      }
    },

    series: [

      // Min
      {
        name: 'Min',
        color: '#C30000',
        data: [
          [2000, 2001],
          [5000, 5001],
          [1000, 1001],
          [8000, 8001],
          [3500, 3501]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'right',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Min (Line)',
        color: '#C30000',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [2000],
          [5000],
          [1000],
          [8000],
          [3500]
        ]
      },

      // Med
      {
        name: 'Med',
        color: '#215994',
        data: [
          [3000, 3001],
          [6001, 6002],
          [3001, 3002],
          [9001, 9002],
          [4001, 4160]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'center',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Med (Line)',
        color: '#215994',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [3000],
          [6001],
          [3001],
          [9001],
          [4001]
        ]
      },

      // Max
      {
        name: 'Max',
        color: '#ECEC09',
        data: [
          [4000, 4001],
          [7001, 7002],
          [5001, 5002],
          [9501, 9502],
          [4501, 4502]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'left',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Max (Line)',
        color: '#ECEC09',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [4000],
          [7001],
          [5001],
          [9501],
          [4501]
        ]
      }

    ]

  });

});
```